# Allocating Memory For Struct in MIPS Specific Example

Tags: mips

I would like to allocate memory for a struct in MIPS which could contain 3 integers (4*3 = 12 bytes) long. How would I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An array, for any practical purposes, must be created in memory.&nbsp This is because only memory can be indexed, so expected operations on an array (e.g. indexing) can only be performed when it is in memory.

However, a struct can be created:

As a local variable:

- in registers — just use as many registers as needed for the bits in the state, e.g. here, 3 registers.  To access fields, use the register(s) holding the field and extract the data desired.
- on the stack — allocate like an int but with different size, use 12 bytes of stack space: increase your stack space allocation by 12 bytes.  To access fields, use an offset that refers to the word(s) containing the field.

As non-local variable:

- as a global — declare enough storage to hold the struct, just like an int but with different sizing (and possibly different alignment).
- in the heap — allocate (malloc/calloc) some memory in the size needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [MARS IDE](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/) to write MIPS code, you can use syscall 9 to request bytes (similar to malloc in C). This allocation happens from the process's heap space. MIPS syscall references in MARS are [here](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html).

This is how you can use this -

```
li  $a0, 12         # number of bytes to request (12 bytes here)
li  $v0, 9          # syscall for performing the request
syscall             # issue syscall

# now $v0 contains the *address* of the 12-byte block allocated.
# You would want to remember $v0 somewhere.
sw  $t0, ($v0)      # E.g usage - store $t0 as 0th int (4 bytes) in the struct
sw  $t1, 4($v0)     # E.g usage - store $t1 as 1st int (4 bytes) in the struct
sw  $t2, 8($v0)     # E.g usage - store $t1 as 2nd int (4 bytes) in the struct
```